# Валидация данных в форме

Tags: php

Создать форму для ввода электронного адреса в формате vasya.pupkin@ukr.net, пароль и подтверждение пароля. При нажатии на кнопку, должна проводиться проверка на валидность введенных данных включая
проверку наличия в пароле хотя бы 3 цифры и хотя бы 1 большой буквы
латинского алфавита. Вывести сообщение об успехе/неуспехе проверки
валидности.

```
<?php
echo "<hr>";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        throw new Exception('некорректный адрес');
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['pass']) < 3) 
    {
        throw new Exception('длина пароля не менее 3х символов');
    }
    if ($_POST['rpass'] !== $_POST['pass']) 
    {
        throw new Exception('пароли не совпадают');
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Стоп Валидация</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" class="form1" method="POST">
        
        <input class="inp" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email: vasya.pupkin@ukr.net">
        <br><br>

       <input class="inp" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
       <br><br>

       <input class="inp" type="password" name="rpass" placeholder="Repeat password">
       <br><br>
       <button name="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Сейчас выдает ошибку, как привязать это к кнопке? (чтоб после нажатия проверялась валидность)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        if (strlen($_POST['pass']) > 3) {
            if ($_POST['rpass'] == $_POST['pass']) {
                echo 'все ок!';
                // Тут код если валидация пройдена
            } else {
                echo '<font color="red">пароли не совпадают</font>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<font color="red">длина пароля не менее 3х символов</font>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<font color="red">некорректный адрес</font>';
    } 
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Стоп Валидация</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" class="form1" method="POST">
        
        <input class="inp" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email: vasya.pupkin@ukr.net">
        <br><br>

       <input class="inp" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
       <br><br>

       <input class="inp" type="password" name="rpass" placeholder="Repeat password">
       <br><br>
       <button name="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: я поправил, только сообщение о валидации нету

Comment: @Yoda просто $_POST. опечатался( или тогда так if (isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: @Yoda Сообщения не выводятся потому, что вы их не выводите. Бросание исключения не выводит на экран ошибку (точнее это очень сильно зависит от настроек)

Comment: @Yoda исправил, копируй. ты бы рассказал поподробнее что ты хочешь? ни чего не понятно но очень интересно)

Comment: @JonBrasers все правильно ты понял, последний момент: как сделать валидацию на 1 заглавную букву? метод ctype_upper()?

Comment: @Yoda через легулярку, у меня так if (preg_match("#^[A-z0-9]{6,30}$#", $_POST['pass'])) { но заглавные не обязательно, не помню как точно( почитай тут  https://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

Comment: @JonBrasers спасибо за помощь!